# Pointers - passing ptr to a ptr or passing address of a ptr

Tags: c++, pointers

I am trying to remove the left child (10) of a sample binary search tree using two methods:

- Method1: By passing pointer to a pointer to the current node.
- Method2: By passing address of the pointer to the current node. This does not removes the node, but calling delete corrupts the pointer arrangement, causing a crash while printing the nodes.

The tree looks like this and I am trying to delete 10 and replace it with 5

> ```
>        20
>        |  
>    10--|---30
>     |
> 5---|
> ```

I have some understanding of pointers. But still, I am not clear with this behavior of pointers.

```
#include <iostream>
class Node
{
public:
    Node(int key) : leftChild(0), rightChild(0), m_key (key){}
    ~Node(){}

    Node *leftChild;
    Node *rightChild;
    int m_key;
};

Node* build1234(int, int, int, int);
void print(Node *);
void print1234(Node *);

void removeLeft(Node **nodePtr)
{
    Node *oldPtr = *nodePtr;
    if(*nodePtr)
    {
        *nodePtr = (*nodePtr)->leftChild;
        delete oldPtr;
    }
}

int main()
{
    Node *demo1 = build1234(10, 20, 30, 5);
    Node *demo2 = build1234(10, 20, 30, 5);
    print1234(demo1);
    print1234(demo2);

    //Method1 - 10 is correctly removed with 5
    Node **nodePtr = &demo1;
    nodePtr = &(*nodePtr)->leftChild;
    removeLeft(nodePtr);
    print1234(demo1);

    //Method2 - 10 is not removed
    Node *node = demo2;
    node = node->leftChild;
    removeLeft(&node);
    print1234(demo2);       
    return 0;
}

Node* build1234(int B, int A, int C, int D)
{
    Node *root = new Node(A);
    root->leftChild = new Node(B);
    root->rightChild = new Node(C);
    root->leftChild->leftChild = new Node(D);
    return root;
}
void print(Node *node)
{
    if(node)
    {
        print(node->leftChild);
        std::cout << "[" << node->m_key << "]";
        print(node->rightChild);
    }
}

void print1234(Node *node)
{
    std::cout << std::endl;
    print(node);
}
```

**Note:** This question is not about BST, but pointers. If you see the two calls to `removeLeft(nodePtr)` and the `removeLeft(&node)` in the `main()` function.

1. How are these two different?
2. Why the second method fails to achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first case, you are passing an address of a pointer that exists in the tree, so you are modifying the contents of the tree directly.

In the second case, you are passing an address of a variable that is local to main() instead. The tree is not modified, and deleting from the address is accessing stack memory, which is why it crashes

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more? `removeNode(nodePtr)` vs `removeNode(&node)`. I agree that `nodePtr` and `&node` are different but `*nodePtr` and `node` are pointing to the same location.

Comment: After a lot of thought :) and pen/paper work, I have understood what you are trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

You're overthinking it. All you need is a function `removeLeft(Node*)` that unhooks the left node and deletes it, recursively:

```
void removeLeft(Node * p)
{
  removeBoth(p->leftChild); // recurse, OK if null

  delete p->leftChild;  // OK if already null
  p->leftChild = 0;     // necessary to make recursion terminate
}

void removeBoth(Node * p)
{
  if (!p) return;

  removeLeft(p);
  removeRight(p);
}
```

Comment: If I am deleting node(10) in the given binary searching tree, it should be replaced with node(5). Your code is deleting up the entire tree.

Comment: That's true. Your question didn't say that you want to reconstitute the tree. What if `10` has two children?

Comment: Sorry, if my question was not clear. It is not about BST, but pointers. If you see the two calls to `removeLeft()` in the main() function. One of them works fine and the second one does not.

Answer (score 0):

If you are bad with pointers consider using smart pointers.
When using smart pointers use `shared_ptr<Node>` instead of `Node *` and `make_shared(new Node);` instead of `new Node` and remove all deletes. now you can handle pointers without caring for deletes and memory corruption.